# "Cookies are disabled" on Login with Webclient

Tags: c#, cookies, web

I am trying to login to a Website using the following Code

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
string formUrl = "https://dualis.dhbw.de/scripts/mgrqcgi"; 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
request.Referer = "https://dualis.dhbw.de";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)) {
    writer.Write("usrname=" + username + "&pass=" + password);
}
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        String result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But the Website says something like "Your Browsers cookies are disabled…"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have not posted all the required code.  You reference a variable **cookieContainer** yet I don't see the variable being declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Website sets a Cookie on a previous Page.

After getting that Page and the Cookie the Login works.